# Modify a recently created spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been working on a script that allows me to modify a recently created spreadsheet.
Here's what I want to do:

1. Create new spreadsheet
2. Copy a sheet from current spreadsheet into new spreadsheet
3. Replace name of new sheet in new spreadsheet.

Here is the code that I have created but when I run it I am able to create the spreadsheet but the sheet from the original spreadsheet is not copied into the new spreadsheet.Basically I am able to create the spreadsheet but once created I am not able to write on the new one.  Any ideas??"

```
function dashboards(){
   //creates dashboards
   var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   ss1.setActiveSheet(ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
   var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("New spreadsheet").getId();
   var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssNew).setActiveSpreadsheet;
   ss1.copyTo(ssNew)
   ssNew.renameActiveSheet("newsheet");;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were pretty close, but I can't follow along all the variable references. Here is re-written version that worked for me.

I think the main issue might be the hanging `setActiveSpreadsheet` call in line 6 that might have broken your variable assignments.

Another key point to make is that you can get a reference to the sheet in the new spreadsheet back from the `copyTo` call

```
function dashboards(){
   var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var origSheet = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create('New spreadsheet').getId();
   var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssNew);
   var newSheet = origSheet.copyTo(ss2);
   newSheet.setName('newsheet');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Arun! This worked as a champ, I really appreciated it.